# WSO2 3.0 not able to open /carbon component

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 3.0, I am not able to open the carbon component.

https://{localhost}:9443/carbon

Comment: Which WSO2 product are you talking about? What is the actual endpoint you are trying to connect to?  Is it a remote machine?

Comment: do you see any errors in the server console?

Comment: Are you asking about WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0?

Comment: did the running of wso2 got success, check in logs for the url .